# Filter a listing in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello I tried Symfony and I'm a very novice.
I am looking for an elegant way to filter listings.

Let me explain:

I have two entities: Link and Tag. They are in multiple relation.

On my index view I created this form. I did a findAll() to get all my tags for the select:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit"/>
    <select name="tags[]" class="selectpicker" multiple="yes">
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <option value="{{ tag.id }}"> {{ tag.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the way I grab all link order by DESC:

```
$links = $em->getRepository('TestDefaultBundle:Link')->findBy(
    array(),
    array('id' => 'desc')
);
```

How can I collect the selected tags (in the controller) and grab all links filter by these selected tags.

Another question I know we can generate a form for an entity but what about this kind of form?

**EDIT**

This is my indexAction:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $tags = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:LinkTag')->findAll();

    // Create the filter form.
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LanCrmBundle:LinkTag',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.title', 'ASC');
            }
        ))
        ->add('OK', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        // Get all links filtered by tags.
        // How to use the $data to filter my links?
        $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'desc')
        );
    } else {
        // Get all links.
        $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'desc')
        );
    }

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $links,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
        4
    );

    return $this->render('LanCrmBundle:Link:index.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'tags' => $tags,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I've got this error :

A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.

StringCastException: A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the best practice is to create Type classes. A great bundle to make filters is 
https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle

And I created a typeGuesser Bundle that uses lexik's types for creating a filterForm with your EntityFormType class as parameter. https://github.com/juanmf/FilterTypeGuesserBundle

With both bundles installed, and your Type Class in place, the code reduces to this for the filter and a method (I left an example in the README.md) for creating the query.

```
    private function createFilterForm($docType)
    {
        $adapter = $this->get('dd_form.form_adapter');
        $type = $this->getFormForDocument($this->getClassFromDocType($docType));
        return $adapter->adaptForm(
            $type,
            $this->generateUrl('document_search', array('docType' => $docType)),
            array('pdfPath', 'pdfPages', 'batchStatus', 'createdInBatch', 'documentType')
            );
    }
```

**Note:** as of Sf >= 2.8 formTypes changes to FQCN, so the typeGuesser can't find type names. Fix needed.

Comment: NOTE: as of Sf >= 2.8 formTypes changes to FQCN, so the typeGuesser can't find type names. Fix needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct way for handling forms - check [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).

Solution might be:

controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('tag', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'TestDefaultBundle:YoutTagEntity',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.title', 'ASC')
            },))
        ->add('OK', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
            // data is an array of values from form, for example: $data['tag']
            $data = $form->getData();

        //here you can now pass variables to another query
        $links = $em->getRepository('TestDefaultBundle:Link')->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'desc')
        );
    }

    // ... render the form
```

twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```